# Ajax error on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, mobile

Hi the below code works well on desktop, but ajax call fails on mobile browsers. On mobile it returns "number". Any help will be appreciated.
On desktop i have tried on firefox, IE and chrome. On Android tried on dolphin, chrome and samsung inbuilt browser.

```
var url="../eXploreAPI/api";
    function login(){
        var number , password;
        number = $("#number1").val();
        password = $("#password1").val();
        var token= btoa(number +":"+password);
        $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'token':token
                },
                type: 'POST', 
                datatype: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: {
                    requestName: "login" ,
                    mobileno : number,
                    password : password
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var d=jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                    var item=d.item;
                    var val = item.userid;
                    getdetails(val);

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert(number);
                }
        });



    }
    function getdetails(val){
        localStorage.setItem("shop_id",val);
        window.location.href="../page4.html";
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your error callback put this line
alert(data.status);
This will give you exact error code. I think this may be issue with cross browser compatibility